# JSON and unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Considering this result I get from an ajax call:

```
 [
    {
        "field1": "2381",
        "field2": "1233",
        "field3": "43.79489333333333",
        "field4": "11.22697833333333"
    },
    {
        "field1": "2381",
        "field2": "1774",
        "field3": "45.70752833333334",
        "field4": "9.489278333333333"
    }
]
```

and having an ajax call it keeps returning "unexpected character" error and I have this kind of call I use:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/myUrl.php",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var arrayObjects = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

So since I read on the internet this kind of ajax calls, it says:

```
[{"value": "test"}] is valid
```

So I wonder why my object keeps returning "unexpected character".

Comment: *Where* does your code return "unexpected character"? What is the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: this is the output of console.log(data):
[Object { field1="2381", field2="1233", field3="43.79489333333333", more...}, Object { field1="2381", field2="1774", field3="45.70752833333334", more...}]

Comment: it's already in the JSON format, not a string

Comment: @Moho, "it's already in the JSON format, not a string" Perhaps you meant "it's already an object, not a JSON string"? JSON is always a string, when you are using the JSON syntax in your code to create native objects it's simply an object literal, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting  `dataType: "json"` you are telling jQuery to parse the received data as JSON, so data is delivered to the success() function as a Javascript array.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3):

When using [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), if you specify the `dataFormat`, it will try to automatically parse the response according to the specified format before passing the data to the callback function.

Therefore, what you receive in your callback is not a JSON string, it's a JavaScript object already, which doesn't require any parsing.

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json", // <-- this specifies the data format already
    url: "/myUrl.php",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]); //logging first record
        //var arrayObjects = JSON.parse(data); //not needed

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the **`data`** returned from the API is already an **`array`**.

*You're trying to parse an array*, so the error.

so change

```
var arrayObjects = data;
```

Comment: but in the PHP I use this line of code:  
    echo json_encode($results);